# Is there any way to prevent chrony stratum plus one?

Tags: synchronization, ntpd, chrony

When using chrony, I synchronize the time from the clock source of stratum=2. Is there any way to prevent my machine from stratum=3, but stratum is equal to 2?

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

> this is my machine

```
MS Name/IP address          Stratum  Poll Reach LastRx Last sample
=====================================================================================
^* 10.211.55.22                   3     6   377    51   -1374us[-2993us]  +/-   179ms
```

> this is the External clock source

```
MS Name/IP address          Stratum  Poll Reach LastRx Last sample
=====================================================================================
^* cn.ntp.faelix.net               2   7    377   129    +231us[+2929us]  +/-   216ms
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: Are you asking (a) to prevent your machine from using sources whose stratum is higher than 2? or (b) that you think your machine should also be stratum=2 because that's what you're syncing to?

Comment: I want my machine stratum=2 ，like the stratum of the external clock source.

Comment: Connect a suitable GPS receiver to your machine, and then it can be stratum=1 instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NTP stratum levels are incremented at each "hop" -- since you're synchronized to a stratum 2 device, your stratum is calculated to be 3.

From the NTP [How does it work? FAQ](http://www.ntp.org/ntpfaq/NTP-s-algo.htm#Q-ALGO-BASIC-STRATUM):

> Basically (and from the perspective from a client) it [*stratum*] is the number of servers to a reference clock.
>
> A server synchronized to a stratum n server will be running at stratum n + 1. The upper limit for stratum is 15. The purpose of stratum is to avoid synchronization loops by preferring servers with a lower stratum.

Comment: So there is no way to avoid stratum n+1, this is the inherent mechanism of chronyd or ntpd

Comment: That's correct, @nbamboo.